# How well do ARX algorithms preform (in terms of diffusion)?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, arx

I have been researching ARX algorithms, but I would like to know how well does ARX (both single or multiple rounds of) provide diffusion compared to an s-box or an SP network.

Also, are there any modifications you can make to an ARX algorithm to make it provide more diffusion?

Comment: A single step of ARX doesn't do nearly as much diffusion as a good sbox; however each step of ARX is real cheap (at least, on a CPU), so you can throw a lot of rounds at the problem...